# Telegram bot with threading - limit Thread with single instance; proper start/stop of the Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, telegram, python-multithreading, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make telegram bot which will make some monitoring.
I've done some research and experiments and think proper way for doing this is to use threading.
Currently I've done more or less working prototype, code below. 
And faced with following issues, which hope you can help to solve.

1. A lot time I've spent to make possible to start and stop monitoring thread in a proper way. And now I'm using Thread variable as global to modify it's status. Is it correct using in my code? Maybe there is a better solution for this?
2. Although this is an unlikely case, but I would like to limit thread with only one istance - so it's not duplicating. As all monitoring will be held in one thread. Can someone help me with this?
3. Maybe some other critical issues in code which are hurting eyes?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, Filters, MessageHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, PicklePersistence
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from telegram.error import NetworkError, Unauthorized, TimedOut
import logging
import os
from datetime import timedelta
import pickle
import numpy as np
import requests
import time
import json
import threading
from threading import Thread

dn = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


# Token for telegram bot
TOKEN=xxx

# Pickle to store unique users
USERS_PICKLE = os.path.join(dn,"users.pkl")
# Pickle to store megarmarket and ashan notification users
SOME_USERS_PICKLE = os.path.join(dn,"some_users.pkl")

# Enable logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 
###...etc

#######################################################
# Class for monitoring thread
class Monitoring(Thread):
    def __init__(self, updater):
        super(Monitoring, self).__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.updater = updater

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            # some monitoring - get request, check result.. etc. if Ok  - send message.
            try:
                with open(SOME_USERS_PICKLE, 'rb') as f:
                        some_registered_users = pickle.load(f)
            except:
                some_registered_users = {}

            del_plan = get_result()
            status = check_status(del_plan)
            if status[0]:
                for usr in some_registered_users.keys():
                    try:
                        self.updater.bot.send_message(chat_id=usr, text="XXX smthng{},{}".format(status[1],status[2]), disable_web_page_preview=True)
                    except Unauthorized:
                            logger.info("User have blocked bot: {},{}".format(usr, check_status_stores[usr])) 
                    except TimedOut:
                            logger.info("Message sending timed out..")                         
            else:
                for usr in some_registered_users.keys():
                    try:
                        self.updater.bot.send_message(chat_id=usr, text="")
                    except Unauthorized:
                            logger.info("User blocked bot: {},{}".format(usr, check_status_stores[usr])) 
                    except TimedOut:
                            logger.info("Message sending timed out..") 

            # some another group monitoring..
            try:
                with open(SOME_USERS_PICKLE2, 'rb') as f:
                        some_registered_users = pickle.load(f)
            except:
                some_registered_users = {}

            del_plan = get_result_2()
            status = check_status_stores(del_plan)
            if status[0]:
                for usr in some_registered_users.keys():
                    try:
                        self.updater.bot.send_message(chat_id=usr, text="XXX smthng{},{}".format(status[1],status[2]), disable_web_page_preview=True)
                    except Unauthorized:
                            logger.info("User have blocked bot: {},{}".format(usr, check_status_stores[usr])) 
                    except TimedOut:
                            logger.info("Message sending timed out..")                         
            else:
                for usr in some_registered_users.keys():
                    try:
                        self.updater.bot.send_message(chat_id=usr, text="")
                    except Unauthorized:
                            logger.info("User blocked bot: {},{}".format(usr, check_status_stores[usr])) 
                    except TimedOut:
                            logger.info("Message sending timed out..") 

##############################################################     



# Define command handlers
def start(update, context):
    logger.info("User {} started bot".format(update.effective_user["id"])) #update.message.chat_id
    update.message.reply_text('Hi, {}'.format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
    #custom keyborad
    custom_keyboard = [['/start', '/help'],['/monitor_']]  #'
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=custom_keyboard, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                     text="Select '/monitor_'",
                     reply_markup=reply_markup)
    # save unique users to pickle (open existing)
    try:
        with open(USERS_PICKLE, 'rb') as f:
                registered_users = pickle.load(f)
    except:
        registered_users = {}
    registered_users[update.effective_chat.id] = (update.effective_user["first_name"], update.effective_user["last_name"])
    with open(USERS_PICKLE, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(registered_users, f)
    logger.info("user dict: {}".format(registered_users))



# Stop monitoring Thread        
def stop_monitoring(update, context): 
    global monitoring  
    update.message.reply_text('End monitoring...')
    monitoring.running = False # stop the thread

# Get some data from monitoring Thread
# def get(update, context, t=monitoring):
#     update.message.reply_text('OK, the current value is {}'.format(t.data))


def help(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                            text=""" bla-bla""")



def select_(update, context):
    a_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']       
    inline_kb=[]
    crossIcon = u"\u274C"
    checkIcon = u"\u2705" 
    for s in a_list:
        inline_kb.append([InlineKeyboardButton(text=checkIcon+" "+s, callback_data="monitoring_ "+s), InlineKeyboardButton(text=crossIcon+" Unsubscribe "+s, callback_data="unsubscribe_ "+s)])       
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_kb)
    update.message.reply_text('Оберіть магазин:', reply_markup=reply_markup)    

def register_monitoring_user(update, context):
    logger.info("User {} registered for {}".format(update.effective_user["id"],update.callback_query.data)) 
    query = update.callback_query
    code = query.data.split(' ')[-1]
    context.bot.answer_callback_query(query.id, "You are registering for {}".format(code))
    #query.edit_message_text(text="Prediction for: {}".format(query.data))
    if code=='A':
        # save users to pickle (open existing)
        try:
            with open(SOME_USERS_PICKLE, 'rb') as f:
                    registered_users = pickle.load(f)
        except:
            registered_users = {}
        registered_users[update.effective_chat.id] = (update.effective_user["first_name"], update.effective_user["last_name"])
        with open(SOME_USERS_PICKLE, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(registered_users, f)
        logger.info("A user dict: {}".format(registered_users)) 

    elif code=='B':
    #.......

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="...".format(code))  


def unsubscribe_monitoring_user(update, context):
    logger.info("User {} unsubscribed from {}".format(update.effective_user["id"],update.callback_query.data)) 
    query = update.callback_query
    code = query.data.split(' ')[-1]
    context.bot.answer_callback_query(query.id, "You are unsubscribing..{}".format(code))
    if code=='A':
        # save users to pickle (open existing)
        try:
            with open(SOME_USERS_PICKLE, 'rb') as f:
                    registered_users = pickle.load(f)
                    registered_users.pop(update.effective_chat.id, None)
        except:
            registered_users = {}
        with open(SOME_USERS_PICKLE, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(registered_users, f)
        logger.info("A user dict: {}".format(registered_users)) 

    elif code=='B':
    #.....
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Unsubscribed..".format(code))  


def unknown(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="WTF "+update.message.text+"? ")
def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)



############ request processing
def get_result():
    url = "google.com"
    headers = {"authority":"xxx"
               ,"path":"/xxx3"
               ,"origin":"xxxx"
               ,"referer":"xxx"
               ,"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36"
               ,"x-chain":"yyy"}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Connection refused")
        return False    
    # print the response status code
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code==200:
        try:
            return response.json()
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            print("Response Not JSON: {}".format(response.text))
            return False
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return False
    else:
        logger.info("Error in response: {}".format(response.status_code)) 
        return False

def get_result_2():
    url = "google.com"
    headers = {"authority":"xxx"
               ,"path":"/xxx3"
               ,"origin":"xxxx"
               ,"referer":"xxx"
               ,"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36"
               ,"x-chain":"yyy"}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Connection refused")
        return False    
    # print the response status code
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code==200:
        try:
            return response.json()
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            print("Response Not JSON: {}".format(response.text))
            return False
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return False
    else:
        logger.info("Error in response: {}".format(response.status_code)) 
        return False


def check_status(json):
    if json==False:
        return(False, False, False)
    else:
        status = None
        for day in json:
            for slot in day[list(day.keys())[1]]:
                if slot['is_open']:
                    status = True
                    date = slot['date']
                    time = slot['time_range']
                    return(status, date, time)
        return(False, False, False)

############

def main():

    # Register handlers in Dispatcher
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start) # start handler
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)   # register start handler
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('monitor_', select_))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('stop_monitoring', stop_monitoring))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(register_monitoring_user, pattern=r'^monitoring_ ')) 
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(unsubscribe_monitoring_user, pattern=r'^unsubscribe_ ')) 
    #
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.command, unknown))
    #error logging handler
    updater.dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)


    # Run bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Start monitoring in thread
    global monitoring  
    monitoring = Monitoring(updater) # create parallel thread
    monitoring.daemon = True # stop the thread if the main thread quits
    monitoring.start()
    print(threading.active_count())



    # Stop the Bot when Ctrl+C received
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info("Starting bot")
    main()
```